# How delete elem in cell?

Tags: javascript

Code Otput after atempt add cell: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

```
let name   = document.querySelector('#name');
let price  = document.querySelector('#price');
let amount = document.querySelector('#amount');
let add    = document.querySelector('#add');
let table  = document.querySelector('#table');
let total  = document.querySelector('#total');

function createCell(tr, value, name) {
    let td = document.createElement('td')
  td.textContent = value
  td.classList.add(name)
  tr.append(td)
}

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    createCell(tr, name.value, 'name');
    createCell(tr, price.value, 'price'); 
    createCell(tr, amount.value, 'amount');
    createCell(tr, price.value * amount.value, 'cost');
    createCell(tr, 'delete', 'remove').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      ev.target.closest('tr').remove()
  })
    table.appendChild(tr);
  recountTotal()
});
```

Comment: `createCell` doesn't return anything

Comment: How to fix it problem?

Comment: You need to `return` the `td` you're creating in the function, assuming that's what you want to add your click to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says, you're trying to call `addEventListener` on `undefined` value.
It means that `createCell` doesn't return anything.

To resolve the issue you have to return `td` you've created inside.
So your updated function should look like this:

```js
function createCell(tr, value, name) {
  let td = document.createElement('td')
  td.textContent = value
  td.classList.add(name)
  tr.append(td)  

  return td
}
```